# Assigning functional relu to a variable while inplace parameter is True

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, in-place, relu

If I want to do ReLU operation after my convolution on x, and in my code I do:

```
x = F.leaky_relu(x, negative_slope=0.2, inplace=True)
```

Is this code wrong since I assign the relu to x variable while `inplace` is `True`? Ie. does it mean the ReLU function ran twice and in order to work correctly I should set the `inplace` to `False` or not assign to x?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will take the tensor x and apply LeakyReLU operation on it. Inplace means you change x directly so your don't need to assign it.

So either you write

```py
F.leaky_relu(x, negative_slope=0.2, inplace=True)
```

or

```py
x = F.leaky_relu(x, negative_slope=0.2)
```

The default value of inplace is False, that's why I don't set it in the second example.

In both cases the operation is executed once